# SQL pivot data based on a column and then also include that pivoted column as part of the column title

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery

in GBQ, I am trying to pivot data based on a date column and then also include that date as part of the column title. Is something like this possible in GBQ or would I need to use pandas and create a column index and then flatten it?

I have tried pivoting in SQL dynamically but i can't figure out how to get dynamic with the column names

[image]

Comment: *I have tried pivoting in SQL dynamically* ... where is your attempt? Why is pandas tagged here? Please post attempted code.

Comment: @Parfait  Because I am asking what is the best way to do this and suggested pandas an an option?

Comment: Asking best way or practice on StackOverflow is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) since it can lead to opinionated answers. We help programmers who make an earnest attempt at a solution. Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) a pandas/SQL solution, give it a try, and ask a specific question on your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

In pandas, you can do this with `df.pivot()` and then use `map()` to join the multi-index column together.

```
data = {'item': ['circle', 'square', 'circle', 'square', 'circle', 'square'],
        'color': ['red', 'green', 'red', 'green', 'red', 'green'],
        'date': ['Dec_22', 'Dec_22', 'Jan_23', 'Jan_23', 'Feb_23', 'Feb_23'],
        'sales': [10,15,20,30,10,12],
        'units': [5,7.5,10,15,5,6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_want = df.pivot(index   = ['item', 'color'], 
                   columns = ['date'], 
                   values  = ['sales', 'units']
                  )

df_want.columns = df_want.columns.map('_'.join)
df_want = df_want.reset_index()
```

```
     item  color  sales_Dec_22  ...  units_Dec_22  units_Feb_23  units_Jan_23
0  circle    red          10.0  ...           5.0           5.0          10.0
1  square  green          15.0  ...           7.5           6.0          15.0
```